# Create new instance of certain html contentusing jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a modal box that loads certain html content from  that start

lets say I have a link

```
<a href='#'>LINK</a>
```

Now and I have the content to be loaded using modal which is hidden and loads when LINK is clicked on

```
<div id='modal'>
// more content goes here

</div>
```

Now I have jQuery that appends more content to it when clicked on the LINK

```
$('#modal').live('click',function(){
// more appending done here
});
```

that above works fine with only one LINK in usage but with multiple links like this

```
 <a href='#'>LINK</a>
 <a href='#'>LINK</a>
 <a href='#'>LINK</a>
```

if I click on each of them , they individually keep appending the same content each time now I know I can use `.empty()` at the start of the each use but I want to know how to do this using `<script type = "text/template"> // content </script>` OR any other way of creating instance of this

Thanks guys

Comment: please create a jsfiddle sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("body").on("click","a",function(){
    var modal = $("<div id="modal"></div>");
    modal.html(<content goes here>);
    return false;
})
```

So every time you click on a tag, you will get a new object in modal variable.